# glutDisplayFunc displays garbage

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to incorporate openGL into my c++ code for the first time. As a start up, I made this very primitive code, which defines a class called polygon and should display a polygon with a method polygon.draw(). Right now, everything below resides in a single main.cpp file, though for easy reading I am separating into section here:

The problem is, the below code compiles and runs alright. Only when the window named "simple" is created, displays garbage (mostly collected from my computer background screen :(.

Firstly, the class polygon:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include "utility.hpp"
#include <vector>

void init(void);

class nikPolygon{
public:
    std::vector<nikPosition> m_vertices;
    nikColor m_color;
    double m_alpha;

    // constructors
    // without alpha (default is 1.0)
    nikPolygon(std::vector<nikPosition> vList, nikColor c):
    m_vertices(vList), m_color(c), m_alpha(1.0){

    }

    nikPolygon(std::vector<nikPosition> vList, nikColor c, double a):
    m_vertices(vList), m_color(c), m_alpha(a){

    }

    // default constructor
    nikPolygon(){

    }


    // member functions
    // add vertex
    void addVertex(nikPosition v)              { m_vertices.push_back(v); }
    // remove vertex
    void removeVertex(nikPosition v);
    // adjust vertex
    void modifyVertex(unsigned int vIndex, nikPosition newPosition);
    // fill color
    void setColor(nikColor col)               { m_color = col; }
    // set alpha
    void setAlpha(double a)                   { m_alpha = a; }
    // display
    void drawPolygon(void){

        // color the objet
        glColor4f(m_color.red, 
                  m_color.green, 
                  m_color.blue, 
                  m_alpha);

        // construct polygon
        glBegin(GL_POLYGON);    
        for (std::vector<nikPosition>::iterator it = m_vertices.begin();
             it != m_vertices.end(); it++)
            glVertex2f(it->x, it->y);
        glEnd();

        // send to screen
        glFlush();

    }

    void draw(void);
};
```

Then the c/c++ callback interface (trampoline/thunk):

```
 // for c++/c callback
 nikPolygon* currentPolygon;

 extern "C"
 void drawCallback(void){
     currentPolygon->drawPolygon();
 }

 void nikPolygon::draw(){
     currentPolygon = this;
     glutDisplayFunc(drawCallback);
 }
```

And then the rest of it:

```
 // initialize openGL etc
 void init(void){

     // set clear color to black
     glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

     // set fill color to white
     glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

     // enable transperancy
     glEnable(GL_BLEND);
     glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

     // setup standard orthogonal view with clipping
     // box as cube of side 2 centered at origin
     // this is the default view
     glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
     glLoadIdentity();
     gluOrtho2D(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);

 }


 int main(int argc, char** argv){

     nikPolygon poly;

     poly.addVertex(nikPosition(-0.5, -0.5));
     poly.addVertex(nikPosition(-0.5, 0.5));
     poly.addVertex(nikPosition(0.5, 0.5));
     poly.addVertex(nikPosition(0.5, -0.5));

     poly.setColor(nikColor(0.3, 0.5, 0.1));
     poly.setAlpha(0.4);


     glutInit(&argc, argv);
     glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
     glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);
     glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);

     glutCreateWindow("simple");
     init();
     poly.draw();
     glutMainLoop();
 }
```

Comment: Be aware that `GL_POLYGON` only handles convex polygons.  Everything else you will have to triangulate yourself.

Comment: Also, the default winding order is counter-clockwise, not clockwise.

Comment: Your code is one of those "well, yes, sure… but… why?" `glutDisplayFunc` is not meant to be used on a per-geometry base. You register a display callback function exactly once, and in that callback iterate over the existing geometry, dispatching the draw call to it.

Comment: Also, you're pushing vertices into a std::vector. Why not pass this vector as a Vertex Array instead of calling immediate mode functions.

Comment: @datenwolf: that's just because I am trying openGL really first-hand. Vertex array seems a better solution.

Comment: @datenwolf: I understand your point about glutDisplayFunc calls per draw() invokation. In fact, that may be the reason, why I get only the last polygon drawn on the screen, even when I define two polygons. Could you suggest a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost, the original code is completely overengineered. This may be part of the original confusion. Also there's not really much you can do, to fix the code, without throwing out most of it. For example representing each polygon (triangle) with a own object instance is about as inefficient as it can get. You normally do not want to do this. The usual approach at representing a model is a *Mesh*, which consists of a list/array of vertex attributes, and a list of faces, which is in essence a list of 3-tuples defining the triangles, making up the surface of the mesh. In class form

```
class Mesh
{
    std::vector<float> vert_position;
    std::vector<float> vert_normal;
    std::vector<float> vert_texUV;

    std::vector<unsigned int> faces_indices;

public:
    void draw();
};
```

Then to draw a mesh you use Vertex Arrays

```
void Mesh::draw()
{
    // This is the API as used up to including OpenGL-2.1

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXCOORD_ARRAY);

    // sizes of attributes depend on actual application
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, &vert_position[0]);
    glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, &vert_normal[0]);
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, &vert_texUV[0]);

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, faces_indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, &faces_indices[0]);
}
```

You put references to these Mesh object instances into a list, or array, and iterate over that in the display function, calling the `draw` method, after setting the appropriate transformation.

```
std::list<Mesh> list_meshes;

void display()
{
    clear_framebuffer();

    set_viewport_and_projection();

    for(std::list<Mesh>::iterator mesh_iter = list_meshes.begin();
        mesh_iter != list_meshes.end();
        mesh_iter++) {
        mesh_iter->draw()
    }

    swap_buffers();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At the beginning of your `drawPolygon` function you need to do a `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);`

Comment: Hi philipvr, thanks a lot for the suggestion. I somehow though (stupidly) that that line will clear the screen :p... BTW, now it does not display the garbage as before, but remains black (i.e. no polygon is displayed.). :(

Comment: I got it.... it was my mistake somewhere else, namely in the position struct, where I have only integer values and hence the vertices weren't taken correctly :(... Thanks a lot... now, solved!